# Clickable Tooltip VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am creating a textbox control, which have some text, i need to compare that text with some variable text and i need to show it as a popup or tooltip nearby the textbox control

My VB.net code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.TextBox1.Text = "Hello world"
        Dim Alternatetext As String = "Hi world"
    End Sub
```

If me.textbox1.text not equal to Alternatetext

Then the display should be as mentioned in the image file attached[image]

If the user clicks accept, the Alternatetext should be replaced into Me.textbox1.text,

Please guide,

I tried to achieve this via standard tooltip, but tooltip click option not available,
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! This site is for programming contests / challenges, not general programming questions. Therefore, I've migrated this over to Stack Overflow, the site for programming questions and answers. Thanks for understanding!

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `InteractiveToolTip` instead. It is an extension to the normal `ToolTip` and does not come with `Visual Studio`. You have to install it from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/529753/InteractiveToolTip-Tooltips-you-can-click-on